# .setAttribute. ReferenceError: element is not defined

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Имеется 2 кнопки. Каждая имеет отдельную функцию по клику. Первая вызывает слайдер с одними картинками, другая - с другими.

При клике на первую кнопку - всё работает: в функции через `setAttribute` присваиваются значения в атрибут `src`. 
При клике на вторую кнопку вылетает ошибка - `ReferenceError: my_img1 is not defined`.

Гугл показывал варианты, что html код ещё не прогружен в момент вызова функции, но я не понимаю почему, ведь при вызове первой кнопки всё работает. Так же я пытался удалять атрибут через `removeAttribute`, а потом снова его присваивать, но это тоже не принесло никаких результатов.

Проще говоря, я хочу сделать так, чтобы при клике по одной кнопке функция загружала картинки в этот слайдер, и он показывал эти картинки. При клике на другую кнопку - другие картинки загружались и так же показывались.

Уже не знаю, какими извращениями это можно сделать, всю голову сломал :( Помогите, пожалуйста.

Код прилагается:

```js
function ImageLoader1() {
  my_img1.setAttribute("src", "http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-640x400.jpg");
  my_img2.setAttribute("src", "http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-640x400.jpg");
  my_img3.setAttribute("src", "http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-640x400.jpg");
  my_img4.setAttribute("src", "http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-640x400.jpg");
  my_img5.setAttribute("src", "http://bipbap.ru/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/0_8eb56_842bba74_XL-640x400.jpg");
  PopUpShow();
}

function ImageLoader2() {
  my_img1.setAttribute("src", "http://www.cruzo.net/user/images/k/ecc3ecf42c75db1ffce5d06cbe95b1e6_644.jpg");
  my_img2.setAttribute("src", "http://www.cruzo.net/user/images/k/ecc3ecf42c75db1ffce5d06cbe95b1e6_644.jpg");
  my_img3.setAttribute("src", "http://www.cruzo.net/user/images/k/ecc3ecf42c75db1ffce5d06cbe95b1e6_644.jpg");
  my_img4.setAttribute("src", "http://www.cruzo.net/user/images/k/ecc3ecf42c75db1ffce5d06cbe95b1e6_644.jpg");
  my_img5.setAttribute("src", "http://www.cruzo.net/user/images/k/ecc3ecf42c75db1ffce5d06cbe95b1e6_644.jpg");
  PopUpShow();
}


function PopUpShow() {
  $("#popup1").fadeIn(500);
}


function PopUpHide() {
  $("#popup1").fadeOut(500);
}
```

```css
.popup_btn {
  font-size: 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  padding: 0.2em 1em;
}

.b-popup {
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
}

.b-popup .b-popup-content {
  margin: 40px auto 0px auto;
  width: 90%;
  height: 90%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: transparent;
}

#FANIPOL,
#GLOSSREITER {
  background-color: lightgrey;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- 3 KB -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>
  <a id="FANIPOL" onclick="ImageLoader1();">Просмотр</a>
  <a id="GLOSSREITER" onclick="ImageLoader2();">Просмотр</a>
</div>

<!-- Gallary -->
<div class="b-popup" id="popup1">
  <div class="b-popup-content">
    <center>
      <div class='fotorama' data-height='80%'>
        <img id="my_img1">
        <img id="my_img2">
        <img id="my_img3">
        <img id="my_img4">
        <img id="my_img5">
      </div>
    </center>
    <center><a class="popup_btn" onclick="PopUpHide();">Закрыть</a></center>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fotorama/4.6.4/fotorama.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var my_img1 = document.getElementById("my_img1");
...
var my_img5 = document.getElementById("my_img5");
```

Comment: да, возможно, но, к сожалению, это не решило проблему. Ссылки на картинки разные, а следовательно по разным кнопкам должны вызываться разные картинки. Если сначала кликнуть на одну кнопку, то слайдер будет с 5ю картинками, указанными в функции. А если кликнуть на другую, то будут опять же эти 5 картинок, точнее последняя из них, хотя должна вызываться другая пятёрка картинок

Comment: @Syncmaxim я ничего не понял

Comment: @Syncmaxim, предполагаю: где-то нужно вызвать `PopUpHide`

Comment: @Syncmaxim, а ещё [тут fotorama.io](http://fotorama.io/) JS скрипт подключают перед дивом `<div class="fotorama">`

Comment: если нажать на первую кнопку - показывается popup с 5ю одинаковыми картинками(цветы), потом перезагрузить страницу, нажать на вторую кнопку - появится popup с 5ю одинаковыми картинками, но уже другими(после, небо). Вот я пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы этот popup вылетал с разными картинками, но без релоуда страницы.

Comment: @qwabra, менял расположения скриптов, не дало никаких результатов, поэтому оставил там

Comment: @qwabra, расставил в предполагаемых местах `popuphide`, но не помогло. Предполагаю, что нужно как-то сделать так, чтобы после вызова первой функции(нажатия первой кнопки) и закрытия этого popup удалялся `src` у `img`, а при нажатии второй сразу же присваивался уже другой `src`. Но я не знаю, как это сделать. `removeAttribute` не помог никак

Answer (score 0):

id'шник не прописался, надёжнее объявлять явно

```
var my_img1 = document.getElementById('my_img1')
```

UPD:

```
<div class="fotorama"
     data-auto="false"></div>

<script>
  $('.fotorama').fotorama({
    data: [
      {img: '1.jpg', thumb: '1-thumb.jpg'},
      {img: '2.jpg', thumb: '2-thumb.jpg'}
    ]
  });
</script>
```

http://fotorama.io/customize/initialization/

Comment: ответил на комментарий выше.

Comment: @Syncmaxim, смотри мой ответ, __UPD__

Comment: @Syncmaxim, правда не факт, что позволит повторно проинициализировать

Comment: не позволит. работает так же, как и я написал. просто здесь, оказывается, я не досмотрел проще способ)
хотя, я могу опять же чего-то не досмотреть

Comment: а если объявить два дива с `class="fotorama"` но разным id и инициализировать через id

Comment: кстати, точно. как очень хороший костыль - подойдёт. однако это только выдержка из большого кода, а таких кнопок у меня 7 ))))
просто думал, что можно найти способ делать это динамически :(

Comment: эм не фанат JQ поэтому сразу не заметил, но заглянув [сюда](https://github.com/artpolikarpov/fotorama/blob/master/src/js/fotorama.js) увидел что функция `fotorama` принадлежит не диву а JQ, и если это так - то должно срабатывать на любом элементе ... ?!

Comment: увидел. Но что ты этим хотел сказать?

Comment: что-то вроде этого `let div = document.createElement('div'); $(div).fotorama({data: [{img: '1.jpg'}]});`

Comment: спасибо. я ещё разберу твой вариант, но пока что запилил костыль, который ты предлагал) ещё раз спс.